# What is the proper h1/h2 markup for second-level pages such as chapters within novel, sections within long article etc.?

Tags: html, seo, semantic-markup

There are cases when **text and image content is too large** to be put onto one single page, but **context is important** for the content in question, so displaying it explicitly makes sense from the UX perspective. For example, this content could be chapters of a novel, parts of a long article, entries in a specialized list of items:

*A Tale in Three Parts*

- The Beginning
- The Middle
- The End

*Local Flora and Fauna*

- Badger
- Mushroom
- Snake

The answer would've been more simple if everything was on the same page, but what if these are separate standalone pages? What should be the proper way to semantically mark headings in that case?

### Option 1

Use same `h1` but different `h2` on all pages:

```
<article>
    <h1>Main Title</h1>
    <h2>Title of Specific Part</h2>
    <p>...</p>
</article>
```

### Option 2

Use `h1` for both article and section even though there is only a single section, and have same top-level `h1` on all pages:

```
<article>
    <h1>Main Title</h1>
    <section>
        <h1 class="styled_like_h2">Title of Specific Part</h1>
        <p>...</p>
    </section>
</article>
```

### Option 3

Optimize for machines, fake styling for humans:

```
<article>
    <p class="styled_like_h1">Main Title</p>
    <h1 class="styled_like_h2">Title of Specific Part</h1>
    <p>...</p>
</article>
```

### Option 4

Optimize for machines and hope humans figure it out from surrounding navigation:

```
(<nav><ul>...breadcrumbs...</ul></nav>)
<article>
    <h1>Title of Specific Part</h1>
    <p>...</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Missing one: `<article>
    <h1>Main Title</h1>
    <section>
        <h2>Title of Specific Part</h2>
        <p>...</p>
    </section>
</article>`

Answer (score 1):

Using your example of a novel displayed as a chapter per page, it would make sense to use a structure like this:

**Title Page**

```html
<head>
  <title>A Tale in Three Parts</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <h1 class="title">A Tale in Three Parts</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <nav>
      <h2>Table of Contents</h2>
      <ol>
        <li><a href="#">The Beginning</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Middle</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The End</a></li>
      </ol>
    </nav>
  </main>
</body>
```

**Chapter Page**

```html
<head>
  <title>A Tale in Three Parts: The Beginning</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav aria-label="Breadcrumbs">
    <ol>
      <li><a href="#">A Tale in Three Parts</a></li>
      <li>The Beginning</li>
    </ol>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <h1 class="chapter">The Beginning</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
  </main>
</body>
```

When thinking about HTML semantics, you should think about it in the context of the HTML document (the page) rather than the broader context of the full content (in this case, the novel). The elements should make sense for the content on the page.

Also remember, semantics aren't just for machines. Users with screen readers, or users for whom stylesheets don't load also benefit from semantic elements. Relatedly, the appearance of text shouldn't dictate which element is chosen. If a large, unique style is desired for a title page, and smaller heading styles are desired for chapter pages, that should be managed through CSS. Both should be `<h1>` elements on their respective pages.

Additionally, using `<article>` to wrap the content of each page isn't appropriate in this example, because articles are meant to be:

> "...a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site, which is intended to be independently distributable or reusable..."
>
> — [MDN Web Docs: The Article Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article)

In the case of a novel, the individual chapters aren't independently distributable.